# Get next post with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql

I've made a very rough and basic CMS as a learning exercise. My next challenge is to create a pagination (next post, previous post).

Ideally, I need to get the next post, if `post_status` is set to `published`.

At the moment I get a post like so:

`SELECT post_title, post_content, post_id, post_status
FROM posts
WHERE post_id='$id'
AND post_status='published'`

In my mind, I would increment the `$id` on the PHP side, like `$id++`. So if I'm on `post_id=19`, I try and get `post_id=20`. However, what happens if that post is **not** set to published — how do I get the next entry, `WHERE post_status='published'`? This could be `21`, `23`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way, say you have an

```
$id = 19;


SELECT post_title,
post_content, 
post_id, 
post_status 
FROM posts 
WHERE post_status='published'
AND post_id > '$id' 
order by post_id
LIMIT 1
```

This will check posts having `id > 19` with  `post_status='published'` and then get the next to 19 by ordering and `limit 1`

**UPDATE** 
As danielsmile commented on getting the previous one for getting last one before  $id = 19; would be pretty same as above

```
SELECT post_title,
    post_content, 
    post_id, 
    post_status 
    FROM posts 
    WHERE post_status='published'
    AND post_id < '$id' 
    order by post_id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is good for getting next post, but OP's CMS uses Last and Next. Modify your answer to reflect this for a +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks! Could you perhaps elaborate on `post_id > '$id'`. Does that get all greater, but `LIMIT 1` reigns it in, so it actually gets 1?

Comment: Yes it will first check id > $id and then since there is an order by clause `order by post_id` it will start ordering from id which is greater than $id in ascending order and limit 1 will limit the returned data to one record which is immediately after the supplied id.

Comment: You've also swapped the `WHERE` and `AND`. Does it matter which comes first in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If the posts are ordered by `id` (maybe ordering by date would be better), You can get the next post using:

```
SELECT post_title, post_content, post_id, post_status
FROM posts 
WHERE port_status = 'published' 
AND id > $id 
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

That means - get all the posts that have higher `id` than the current one. Sort them by `id` ascending and get just the first one. So as a result, it gives You the first posts with the closest higher `id`.